# Get the value of the checked checkbox with on change

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I have an AJAX-loaded list of checkboxes, I want to display an alert with the value of the checked checkbox.

```
$(document).on('change', '.check', function(event) { 
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

For the standard method it's working as `$(this)` is the changed or clicked checkbox, but we can't use this method as the checkboxes are loaded via AJAX after the document has loaded:

```
$('.check').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

Comment: What's the problem with your first script? The delegated event handler is exactly what you should be using for dynamically created elements - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kekutxm9/)

Answer (score 1):

You should write your script as

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: then try this here
    $('.check').on("click",function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });

Answer (score 1):

So, the first script is running now. It was another error not the one declared before.